# Complications with moving data from SQL Server to Excel using VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sql-server-2017

I am trying to extract data from SQL Server into Excel to populate a pre-existing worksheet so I wrote a test code to this this out. While it is imperfect what I was mainly testing was establishing the connection to the server but I run into an Automation error Error 440 when I open the connection. What am I doing wrong within that portion of code.

I haven't made any modifications as of yet and have check to make sure it compiled just fine.

```
Sub GetPhysicalCount()
    Dim squery As String
    Dim cnLogs As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rsData As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rsHeaders As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim dbpath As String
    Dim dbname As String
    Dim AppExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim Workbook As Object
    Dim Worksheet As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim Count As Long


    pUser = "AllenBroady"
    pPsw = "Cthulu90"
    pServer = "IMCPU_TEST"
    pCatalog = "MasterMFG"




    strConn = "Provider = SQLOLEDB;"
    strConn = strConn & "Initial Catalog= & pCatalog; & Data Source= & pServer;"
    strConn = strConn & "Integrated Security=sspi;& User ID= & pUser; & Password= & pPsw;"

    cnLogs.Open strConn

        With rsHeaders

            .ActiveConnection = cnLogs

                    .Open "SELECT * FROM MasterMFG WHERE Dept_Code = 001"

                 Do While Not rsHeaders.EOF

                    Cells(1, l_counter + 1) = rsHeaders(0)

                    l_counter = l_counter + 1

                    rsHeaders.MoveNext

                  Loop

            .Close

            End With

            With rsCount
                  .ActiveConnection = cnLogs
                    .Open "SELECT COUNT(Dept_Code)FROM MasterMFG WHERE Total <> 0"
                      Count = rsCount
                  .Close
            End With



            With rsData

            .ActiveConnection = cnLogs
                .Open "SELECT  Dept_Code, Total FROM MasterMFG WHERE Total <> 0"


               For i = 1 To Count

                    Sheet1.Range("A" & i + 1) = rsData.Fields(i)
                    rsData.MoveNext
                    Sheet1.Range("B" & i + 1) = rsData.Fields(i)
               Next i

            .Close

            End With

        cnLogs.Close

        Set cnLogs = Nothing

        Set rsHeaders = Nothing

        Set rsData = Nothing

    Sheets(1).UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

I keep getting an "Automation" error (Error 440)

Comment: Do you need to use integrated security or a username/password? I believe the problem is that you are doing both.

Comment: Thanks  that was and oversight by myself. I removed it and ran it and still ran into the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `strConn = strConn` strings are not concatenated properly.

Your variables aren't evaluating, their names are just being put straight into the string.

Change, e.g.

```
 strConn = strConn & "Initial Catalog= & pCatalog; & Data Source= & pServer;"
 strConn = strConn & "Integrated Security=sspi;& UserID= & pUser; & Password= & pPsw;"
```

to

```
 strConn = strConn & "Initial Catalog=" & pCatalog & ";Data Source=" & pServer & ";"
 strConn = strConn & "Integrated Security=sspi;User ID= "& pUser; & "Password= " & pPsw & ";"
```

Comment: Thanks I did miss this do.

Comment: I am still running into the same error thought once I try to connect.